# Pasar parámetros a un ejecutable .exe desde Java con exec

Tags: java, txt, exec

He estado intentando hacer un programa que corra un ejecutable .exe que pide como parámetro un archivo txt pero no lo lee el txt.

```
 try {
            Process proceso = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Users\\ivann\\Dropbox\\HomeWork_&_Work Tec\\Implementacion de metodos computacionales\\Hilos\\src\\main.exe", producto).start();
            InputStream is = proceso.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Consumidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Productor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        //}
    }
```

Comment: La variable producto, ¿qué es?, ahí puedes agregar los parámetros que requieres, claro que debería ser String con los parámetros que requieres para ejecutar tu .exe

Comment: La variable producto es la variable que contiene el nombre del archivo .txt